# SQL Server Stored Procedure returns: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting an error because the SELECT/ CASE returns more than one row, I think. I would like to ask for help and learn how can convert my stored procedure from a parameter based on a single row to a parameter-less code and be able to run the stored procedure for multiple records.

The entire message reads:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is my code:

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Desc  NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DESC = 'Beginning of description ';
SET @Desc = @DESC+(
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN LEFT([pd].[Title], 1) = '"'
    THEN CONCAT('&quot;', REPLACE([pd].[Title], '"', ''), '&quot;')
  END
FROM [dbo].[Data_Feed] [df]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductData] [pd]
    ON [df].[sku] = [pd].[ProductID]
WHERE pd.ProductType IN (19, 20, 23, 26, 27));

SET @DESC = (
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN [df].[show] IS NOT NULL
    THEN CONCAT(@DESC, ' from ', [df].[show])
    ELSE CASE
           WHEN [df].[primary_performer] IS NOT NULL
           THEN CONCAT([df].[primary_performer], ' ', @DESC)
           ELSE CASE
                  WHEN [df].[performer] IS NOT NULL
                  THEN CASE
                         WHEN LEN([df].[performer])-LEN(REPLACE([df].[performer], ';', '')) > 1
                         THEN CONCAT(@DESC, ' by ', REPLACE(STUFF([df].[performer], LEN([df].[performer])-CHARINDEX(';',REVERSE([df].[performer]))+1, 1, ' and '), ';', ', '))                                                                                              
                         ELSE CONCAT(@DESC, ' by ', REPLACE([df].[performer],';', ' and '))                                                                                      
                       END
                  ELSE CASE                                                                              
                         WHEN [df].[composer] IS NOT NULL
                         THEN CASE
                                WHEN LEN([df].[composer])-LEN(REPLACE([df].[composer], ';', '')) > 1
                                THEN CONCAT(@DESC, ' by ', REPLACE(STUFF([df].[composer], LEN([df].[composer])-CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE([df].[composer]))+1, 1, ' and '),';', ', '))                                                                                                      
                                ELSE CONCAT(@DESC, ' by ', REPLACE([df].[composer], ';', ' and '))
                              END
                       END
                END
         END
  END
FROM [Data_Feed] [df]);

SET @DESC = @DESC+(
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN [df].[scoring] IS NULL
    THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(@DESC), '.')
    ELSE CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(';', [df].[scoring]) > 0
           THEN CONCAT(' in ', LEFT([df].[scoring], CHARINDEX(';', [df].[scoring], 1)-1), ' format.')
           ELSE CONCAT('  in ', [df].[scoring], ' format.')
         END
  END
FROM [Data_Feed] [df]);

UPDATE [Data_Feed]
SET
  [description] = @Desc         

END;
```

Comment: With complex string manipulations like this, it's going to be necessary to provide some representative test data for [Data_Feed] and the expected/desired output that you want for the description, based on the supplied test values.

Comment: Do you have more than one record in `[Data_Feed]`? If so, how do you suspect it will set multiple values into your @DESC variable?

Comment: Yes the variable @Desc can end up having multiple parts in the concatenated string. Data_Feed  has more then one record.